# How to make a PHP's CURLFile object for uploading in c#?

Tags: c#, php, upload

I'm a newbie in c#, I am writing some winform c# codes to upload a file to server, it comes from PHP, I have almost done but met a small problem.

In PHP, I use curl_file_create to create a CURLFile object, then add this object to curl's parameters, the code is like:

```
$filename = "d:/1.zip";
$fileTitle = "[Test]1.zip";
$data["sess_id"] = $sess_id;
$data["file"] = curl_file_create($filename, mime_content_type(filename), $fileTitle);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

The function curl_file_create create an object like:

```
object(CURLFile)[1]
  public 'name' => string 'd:/1.zip' (length=8)
  public 'mime' => string 'application/zip' (length=15)
  public 'postname' => string '[test]1.zip' (length=11)
```

And in C#, my code is like:

```
string filename = "d:/1.zip";
string fileTitle = "[Test]1.zip";
string parameters = "sess_id=" + sess_id;
byte[] dataParameters = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Encoder 1.0.0）";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.ContentLength = dataParameters.Length;
using (Stream webStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    webStream.Write(dataParameters, 0, dataParameters.Length);
}
webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Then comes the questiom, how can I create a CURLFile object for uploading in c#? Or are there any other methods to reach it?

Comment: At a guess, it looks like the PHP might produce multipart form data.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  Both of these code samples appear to be trying to upload a file to some other server, neither one of these is itself the server.  Which one isn't working as expected?  How is it failing?  Are you just trying to convert PHP code to C# code?  If you're writing C# code to upload a file to a server, have you looked up examples of how to do that?  When you test the code, what happens?

Comment: I agree, it's unclear what's going on here. Another point is that `WebRequest` is effectively deprecated, you should use `HttpClient` instead, along with `MulipartFormDataContent`.